# Flutter state management with Provider

Tags: flutter

I have a simple [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) class:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class AppState with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isLoggedIn = false;
  bool get isLoggedIn => _isLoggedIn;

  set isLoggedIn(bool newValue) {
    _isLoggedIn = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And in the login class I just set `isLoggedIn` to true if login is successful:

```
 void _signInWithEmailAndPassword(appState) async {
    try {
      final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        ...
      );

      if (user != null) {
        appState.isLoggedIn = true;
        appState.userData = user.providerData;
        ...
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _errorMessage = e.message;
      });
    }
  }
```

Pressing the back button on Android lets users go back to this page even after successfully logging in. So I wanted to know if `Provider.of` can be accessed before `Widget build` and redirect a user if `isLoggedIn` is `true`.

Now I have something like:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context);
...
```

This is only one use case for the login view, but I'm sure this functionality can be used in other cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to use the FirebaseUser or Logged in user throughout your app, i would suggest that you add the Provider on the highest level of your app. Example

```
void main() {

   runApp(MyApp());
   }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged, // Provider here
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.green,
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          accentColor: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        home: MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPage({Key key, this.storage}) : super(key: key);
  final FirebaseStorage storage;
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context); // gets the firebase user
    bool loggedIn = user != null;

    return loggedIn ? HomePage() : LoginPage(); // Will check if the user is logged in. And will change anywhere in the app if the user logs in
  }
}
```

References

[Fireship 185 Provider](https://github.com/fireship-io/185-advanced-flutter-firestore)

[Great Youtube video explaining the code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFxk_KJCqgk)

Comment: Thank you. So I made it work ... but how do I add my `AppState` along side the Firebase authentication provider?

Comment: I got it ... I can just do `ChangeNotifierProvider<AppState>.value(notifier: AppState(),),`

Comment: Sorry for late reply i used this, not sure what is the difference between this and yours  `ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => LoadingService(),),`

Comment: Cool. Thank you for the resource. I guess it works both ways. Maybe someone will explain the difference.

Comment: How to use this logic if we are using the naviagtion route?