# Using user's Google account profile picture in Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Good day, I am currently using firebase/flutter to create an app where users can log in to proceed to the next page. My log in and firebase are all in working order, but an issue I'm having is being able to access the user's profile picture on the initial log in. The gif attached shows it better than I can explain, but basically when I log in the first time, the user image is not there, but if I exit and go back in (user still signed in) the picture is then loaded:

[image]

**Issue:** User's profile picture does not load on first log in and only appears if exiting and re-entering while still logged in.

**Assumption:** The user's data does not have enough time to load in by the time my data has finished loading. OR: I am not calling the data correctly on initial log in.

**What I'm aiming for:** Have the user's details (photo/name/email) loaded on clicking of the login button and before the next page is fully loaded.

**Code:**
*Signin button:*

```
Widget _signInButton() {
    return OutlineButton(
      splashColor: Colors.grey,
      onPressed: () async {
        try {
          final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
          if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
            print('connected');
            bool result = await signInWithGoogle(); //assumed issue
            if (result) {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/specials-page');
              fireBaseAnalyticsDataObject.onLogin(result);
            }
            else
              print("error logging in");
          }
        } on SocketException catch (_) {
          noInternetAlertDialog(context);
          print('not connected');
        }
      },
```

*sign-in.dart:*

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
final MyTabsState tabPageObject = new MyTabsState();

Future<bool> signInWithGoogle() async {
  try{
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
    await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );

    final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

    MyTabs(
      userDisplayName: user.displayName,
      userPhotoUrl: user.photoUrl,
      userEmail: user.email,
    );

    globalData.user = user; //this accesses .uid / .displayName / .email / .photoUrl

    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Are you using the provider package?

Comment: I am not. I've read through it now, but don't understand how that would help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56218510/4712391 this might help, if you want to use the provider package. this is used to keep track on the user object and if it change so will your profile pic

Answer (score 0):

If a there's a variable that on the page that has just been updated, calling it inside `setState()` might solve the issue. You need to check if `Image.network()` is being fed with the expected user photo URL after login because the image works as expected on app resume. The code you provided doesn't demonstrate how the photo URL is being accessed and displayed on the landing page.